# Blending two images, error: Images do not match

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, opencv, blending

Trying to blend two images together. 
I am getting an exception of images not matching, not sure what to change or how to manipulate an image so that it matches

two photos: [photo 1](https://drive.google.com/a/sandiego.edu/file/d/15Ej2OSeoOAxfU8Ym0JHIg74EMBF6OQ1E/view?usp=drivesdk), [photo 2](https://drive.google.com/a/sandiego.edu/file/d/1XHSi6-v02uC7qWf67RzOcl226zPgtrqK/view?usp=drivesdk)

```py
fg = Image.open("test.png").convert("RGBA") ## ive done it with and without RGBA
bg = Image.open("newfig.png").convert("RGBA")
# set alpha to .7
Image.blend(bg, fg, .5).save("out.png")
```

I then tried converting using `cv2` for both images

```py
fg = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

```py
fg = Image.open("test.png")
fg = cv2.cvtColor(fg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

bg = Image.open("newfig.png")
bg = cv2.cvtColor(bg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# set alpha to .7
Image.blend(bg, fg, .5).save("out.png")
```

and then the error I get is

> Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src'

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.cvtColor()` expects an source image object created (in general) via `cv2.imread()` (or more specifically an **numpy** array) as it's first argument. But in your code, you are creating `PIL.Image` object using `Image.open()` and passing it to `cv2.cvtColor()` as an argument, which is causing the error.

Just replace all `Image.open()` by `cv2.imread()` and the program should work fine.

```
fg = Image.open("test.png")
bg = Image.open("newfig.png")
```

By

```
fg = cv2.imread("test.png", -1)
bg = cv2.imread("newfig.png", -1)
```

And the program should work fine.

**EDIT:-**

`help(cv2.addWeighted)` says it all:-

> second input array of the same size and channel number as src1 (first array)

Meaning both the images should have same size and mode. In your images (provided in the comment) both the images are of different dimensions (size) and are of different color modes. So, in order to get through this you have to make the *mode* and the *size* of both the images equal.

So you have to convert the image color mode of either one of the image, to match the color mode of the other image. And do the same for their sizes.

You can achieve this by using a Hybrid of `PIL` and `cv2`, or you can do this solely using `cv2` also.

**Hybrid Method:-**

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np

fg = Image.open("test.png")

# converting the color mode of the second image to match the first image, while opening the second image
bg = Image.open("newfig.png").convert(fg.mode)

# resizing the second image to the same dimensions as the first one
bg = bg.resize(fg.size)

# creating an numpy array off both the image objects, for using in addWeighted()
bg = np.array(bg)
fg = np.array(fg)

img = cv2.addWeighted(fg, 0.3, bg, 0.7, 0)
```

**Pure`cv2` Method:-**

```
import cv2

fg = cv2.imread("test.png", -1)
bg = cv2.imread("newfig.png", -1)

# converting color modes of both the images to Greyscale    
fg = cv2.cvtColor(fg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
bg = cv2.cvtColor(bg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# resizing both the images to 400x400 size
fg = cv2.resize(fg, (400, 400))
bg = cv2.resize(bg, (400, 400))

img = cv2.addWeighted(fg, 0.3, bg, 0.7, 0)
```

Comment: so I did that   fg = cv2.imread("test.png", -1)
bg = cv2.imread("newfig.png", -1)
fg = cv2.cvtColor(fg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

bg = cv2.cvtColor(bg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

img = cv2.addWeighted(fg, 0.3, bg, 0.7, 0)

Comment: and now it gives me 209:Sizes of input arguments do not match

Comment: @AricaChristensen then probably the size of numpy array (or the dimensions/color spaces of both the images) may be different. I can't see the images, as you have security on them so please make the images publicly viewable so that i can analyse them

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UeVifqX8AClOW8vSFJ9DR_d1CsOPbiBd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xbB_SJ3Ki8XbIr5jPUmaU-2jzeBWj1ri/view?usp=sharing

Comment: those are the two photos

Comment: @AricaChristensen Edited the Answer.